# Loss is not decreasing in Keras Seq2seq Bidirectional LSTM with Attention

Tags: python, keras, lstm, bidirectional, seq2seq

Anybody can see why the loss in this model is not decreasing?

I tried to integrate a bidirectional LSTM with the attention model at the end of Andrew Ng's Deep Learning specialization 
(https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models/notebook/npjGi/neural-machine-translation-with-attention)
but for some reason the model seems not to be converging

I am running it on Google Colab

The network takes two tensors as an input with shapes:

```
encoder_input_data[m, 262, 28]
decoder_target_data[m, 28, 28]
```

The output is a list of 27 oneHot vectors

The length of the oneHot vectors is 28:

(26 characters from the alphabet + endkey + startkey)

***The overall structure is: ***

0)Input[262,28] ->

1)Encoder: BidirectionalLSTM ->

2)backward and forward are concatenated into `encoder_outputs` ->

3)Decoder LSTM + Attention ->

___*concatenate previous decoded state s with every a(t) of the encoder

___*let it pass through two Dense layer and calculate the alphas

___*sum up every alpha(a(t))*a(t)

4)Softmax layer and get results

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import merge, Input, LSTM, Dense, Bidirectional, concatenate, Concatenate
from keras.layers import RepeatVector, Activation, Permute, Dot, Input, Multiply
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.activations import softmax
from textwrap import wrap
import re
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import copy
from google.colab import files
from google.colab import drive

#drive.mount('/content/drive')
#files.upload()

    #returnData() creates 3 vectors:
    #encoder_input_data[m, 262, 28]
    #decoder_input_data[m, 28, 28] <- not used for now
    #decoder_i_data[m, 28, 28]

#special softmax needed for the attention layer
def softMaxAxis1(x):
    return softmax(x,axis=1)

#layers needed for the attention
repeator = RepeatVector(262)
concatenator = Concatenate(axis=-1)
densor1 = Dense(10, activation = "tanh")
densor2 = Dense(1, activation = "relu")
activator = Activation(softMaxAxis1, name='attention_weights')
dotor = Dot(axes = 1)

#compute one timestep of attention
#repeat s(t-1) for all the a(t) so far and concatenate them so that
#the algorithm can select the old a(t) based on current s
#let a dense layer compute the energies and a softmax decide
def one_step_attention(a, s_prev):
    s_prev = repeator(s_prev)
    concat = concatenator([a, s_prev])
    e = densor1(concat)
    energies = densor2(e)
    alphas = activator(energies)
    context = dotor([alphas, a])    
    return context

#variables needed for the model
encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data, decoder_target_data = returnData()
batch_size = 64
epochs = 50
latent_dim = 128
num_samples = 1000
num_tokens = 28
Tx = 262

#encoder part with a bi-LSTM with dropout
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(Tx, num_tokens))
encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True ,dropout = .7))
encoder_outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)

#decoder part with a regular LSTM
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim*2, return_state=True)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')

#initialize the parameters needed for computing attention alphas 
s0 = Input(shape=(latent_dim*2,))
c0 = Input(shape=(latent_dim*2,))
s = s0
c = c0
outputs=[]

#run attention for each target timestep Ty
for t in range(num_tokens-1):
        context = one_step_attention(encoder_outputs, s)
        s, _, c = decoder_lstm(context, initial_state = [s, c])
        out = decoder_dense(s)
        outputs.append(out)

#define the model and connect the graph
model = Model([encoder_inputs, s0, c0], outputs)

#select optimizer, loss, early_stopping
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
keras_callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30)]

#prepare empty arrays for s0 c0 and put target data in the same for of outputs
s0 = np.zeros((encoder_input_data.shape[0], latent_dim*2))
c0 = np.zeros((encoder_input_data.shape[0], latent_dim*2))
outputs = list(decoder_target_data.swapaxes(0,1))

#fit the model with the expected dimensions of input/output
model.fit(
    [encoder_input_data, s0, c0], 
    outputs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_split=0.1
)

#save and download the model
model.save('s2s.h5')
files.download("s2s.h5")
```

When training I am getting these results:

```
Train on 11671 samples, validate on 1297 samples
Epoch 1/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 719s 62ms/step - loss: 86.7096 - dense_77_loss: 1.0157 - val_loss: 85.6579 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.5682
Epoch 2/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 672s 58ms/step - loss: 87.6775 - dense_77_loss: 2.0322 - val_loss: 88.3077 - val_dense_77_loss: 2.4503
Epoch 3/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 670s 57ms/step - loss: 86.1718 - dense_77_loss: 0.6686 - val_loss: 85.1008 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.1771
Epoch 4/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 666s 57ms/step - loss: 85.1310 - dense_77_loss: 0.1196 - val_loss: 84.8357 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.0205
Epoch 5/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 666s 57ms/step - loss: 84.7977 - dense_77_loss: 0.0173 - val_loss: 84.7414 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.0072
Epoch 6/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 655s 56ms/step - loss: 87.8612 - dense_77_loss: 2.4636 - val_loss: 87.3005 - val_dense_77_loss: 1.3145
Epoch 7/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 662s 57ms/step - loss: 88.1340 - dense_77_loss: 2.5091 - val_loss: 89.6831 - val_dense_77_loss: 4.6627
Epoch 8/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 666s 57ms/step - loss: 88.2948 - dense_77_loss: 2.6113 - val_loss: 86.4465 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.1490
Epoch 9/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 666s 57ms/step - loss: 87.3295 - dense_77_loss: 1.8405 - val_loss: 85.1743 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.1448
Epoch 10/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 661s 57ms/step - loss: 85.0535 - dense_77_loss: 0.1180 - val_loss: 84.8204 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.0236
Epoch 11/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 662s 57ms/step - loss: 84.7884 - dense_77_loss: 0.0179 - val_loss: 84.7479 - val_dense_77_loss: 0.0050
Epoch 12/50
11671/11671 [==============================] - 665s 57ms/step - loss: 87.0466 - dense_77_loss: 1.9977 - val_loss: 89.4181 - val_dense_77_loss: 4.4239
Epoch 13/50
 1216/11671 [==>...........................] - ETA: 9:34 - loss: 89.7864 - dense_77_loss: 4.8242
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to find the issue behind it?